# HttpClient Angular 4 not using proxy api from proxy.conf.js

Tags: angular

I have problem with HttpClient in angular 4. I replaced Http with HttpClient and after that every request using base path(localhost:4200) instead from proxy.conf.js file.

Thanks for help.

Comment: so he's not throwing any errors that your proxy is not working, he's just calling the wrong backend, right?

Comment: yes, calling base url instead defined backend url in proxy.conf.js file. I get 404 error because they don't exist.

Comment: I think you need a json file for the proxy, are you sure your file is named `proxy.conf.js`

Comment: I also tried with proxy.conf.json. {
   "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:29260",
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "secure": false,
      "pathRewrite": { "^/api" : ""}
   }
}. And changed in package.json file to use it and after npm start proxy not created.

Answer (score 0):

When switching from Http to HttpClient, something happens with the proxy config, I'm not sure what it is, but you have to actively set the **http protocol** in front of your proxy address. Also try to store it as a json file (maybe it still works with a .js file, but the structure inside of the file is definitely json).

So here's how your config should look like (regarding your comment code, there shouldn't be a semicolon after your target).

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:29260",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I don't know why but still not working.

Comment: how are you calling the proxy.conf file? In my case I'm calling `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Comment: Also I think as long as your target is on the same host, you don't have to set the `changeOrigin` parameter to `true`

Comment: Yes, same as you.

Comment: You can also set the log level to `debug` to check what's going on with the proxy file: "logLevel": "debug"`

Comment: Now I have message in console that proxy has crated successfully. But still when I'm calling for example: getAllBanners(): Observable<any[]> {

    return this.http.get(routes.banners())
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .map(body => body)
      .catch((err) => this.persistenceService.handleError(err));
  } . I get an error in console GET http://localhost:4200/homebanners/ 404 (Not Found).

Comment: well what does your `routes.banners()` look like?

Comment: banners: () => `/homebannerviews/`,

Comment: Well you are only redirecting calls that start with `api` but this onr isn't

Comment: Interesting is that when I changed in consturctor  HttpClient to Http  constructor(private http: Http) everything works fine.